# EventBus Response inside IntentService

Tags: android, intentservice, android-intentservice, greenrobot-eventbus

On implementing onHandleIntent(Intent inte) of IntentService Class,i need to call a webservice  which is added in another class say "Webservices.Class".Through  **EventBus.getDefault().post(new ResponseEvent())**,it is delivering response in all activities / fragments etc,But it is not delivering the response inside the intentService class which i called.Does anybody came across this situation?

I Used **onEventMainThread(ResponseEvent event)** for receving response

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

*IntentService* is running on back thread so posting it on the main thread wont work.

I guess that u r using *IntentService* becuase of push notification, if u want eventbus then u need to open a *Service* and let it implement the EventBus.